# scanf error handling C

Tags: c, error-handling

Say If i want an input to be

```
[Name] [Name]
```

How would I detect

```
[Name] [Name] [Name]
```

and return error?

Here is what I have so far,

```
char in[20];
char out[20];
scanf(" %s %s", out, in);
```

Comment: Is "don't use `scanf`" an acceptable answer (if we elaborate, of course)?

Comment: Also, are `Name`s guaranteed not to contain whitespace/brackets/crazy characters that muck up the `%s` format string? Is `"[Bruce Wayne]"` valid?

Comment: yes, there is no white space guaranteed, white space will represent next element

Comment: Wold be Name Name then next line Name Name then next line Name Name etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is homework, so you might be required to work under certain (arbitrary) restrictions. However, the phrase "`scanf` error handling" is something of an oxymoron in the C programming language.

The *best* way to do this is to read in a line/other suitable chunk and parse it with C string functions. You can do it in one line of `scanf` but there are many drawbacks:

1. You can guard against buffer overflows, but if a buffer isn't large enough you can't recover.
2. You can specify specific character ranges for your strings, but it starts to look a little regexy, and the behavior of the `"%["` format of `scanf` isn't mandated in the standard.
3. You can check for a third name, but the code looks unintuitive - it doesn't look like you only want two names, it looks like you want three. `scanf` also gives you very little control over how you handle whitespace.

EDIT: I initially thought from your question that the names were contained in brackets (a la `"[Bruce] [Wayne]"`) but it now appears that was merely your convention for denoting a placeholder.

Anyway, despite my intense dislike of `scanf`, it has its uses. The biggest killer (for me) is the inability to distinguish between line endings and simple space separation. To fix that, you can call [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html) to read the data into a buffer, *then* call `sscanf` on the buffer. This gives you both a) safer reading (`scanf` messes with the ability of other more straightforward functions to read from a buffer) and b) the benefits of `scanf` formats.

If you have to use `scanf`, your format basically be this:

```
" %s %s %s"
```

With the third being undesirable. As [@Constantinius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969084/scanf-error-handling-c/5969152#5969152)'s answer shows, you'd need to read data into three buffers, and check whether or not the third passed. However, if you're reading multiple consecutive lines of this data, then the first entry of the next line would satisfy the third slot, falsely giving you an error. I highly recommend using `fgets` and `sscanf` or ditching the `sscanf` for more precise manual parsing in this case.

Here's a link to the [`fgets` man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html) if you missed the one I snuck in earlier. If you decide to ditch `sscanf`, here are some other functions to look into: [`strchr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strchr.html) (or [`strspn`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strspn.html), or [`strcspn`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcspn.html)) to find how long the name is, [`strcpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcpy.html) or [`memcpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memcpy.html) (but please not `strncpy`, it's not what you think it is) to copy data into the buffers.

Comment: sorry, its [Name Name]\n ... possibly more [Name Name]\n

Comment: Are the names delimited by brackets? Is the input `"[Clark] [Kent]\n"` or just `"Clark Kent\n"`?

Comment: Clark Kent\n ... possibly more . So would i be better off reading a whole line first then break it up according to white space ? I done that in java but I have no idea how to do that in C

Comment: All good advice, but I'd go further. Ditch `fscanf` in favor of `getline` (not c standard, but part of POSIX) or one of the many equivalent libraries that can read lines of arbitrary length without risking buffer overflows.

Comment: @dmckee - Or go for GNU readline (or BSD editline) for even more functionality. Even if you don't have those libraries, writing a `getline` (or stripped-down `readline`) function isn't terribly difficult, and once written it certainly saves a lot of time. However, this _is_ just homework, so I'm willing to accept that the professor might not want people trying to figure out `malloc` yet.

Answer (score 5):

`scanf` returns the number of validly converted arguments. So in your first case, the return value would be 2, in the latter case 3.

To check the right amount of parameters, this might help:

```
char in[20];
char out[20];
char error[20];
int check;

check = scanf(" %s %s %s", out, in, error);
if(check != 2)
{
    // TODO: error handling
}
```

EDIT: now it should be working, see comments below.

Of course, as stated by other posters: scanf is not considered a quite safe function since buffer overflows can occur, and you should avoid using it. It is better to read the inputs to a buffer with `fgets()` and the try to parse the arguments you want.

Comment: This won't work, because if there is a third argument, `scanf` will happily leave it waiting in the stream, only scan the first two names, and return 2. This does nothing to check for the possible existence of a third name.

Comment: I must admit that you are right :/ seems like I havent thought this one through enough.

Comment: one silly question, will fgets() give me the same functions ?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. fgets() lets you read from a buffer, like the stdin buffer used for inputs. "fgets(buf,100,stdin);" reads 100 characters from stdin into the buffer buf. Afterwads the buffer can be read with secure functions like sscanf. eg: sscanf(buf, "%20s %20s %20s", out, in, error);

Comment: because in my case, its <name> <name> then there might be a new line of <name> <name>. error might just be read as next line wont it ?

Comment: well, you can consider encapsulating it into a function, so that every time the arguments are parsed, they are parsed in the same manner.