# How to read file by using fscanf?

Tags: c

How can I read file by using `fscanf`? In this case, I cannot handle an error with wrong entry.

```
while (fscanf(stdin, "%lf, %lf, %79[^\n]", &weight, &age, name) == 3){
    //something
}
```

I have a file A that is:

```
150, 20, 'John'

129, 20, 'Jimmy'

123,,,,,,

201, 20, 'Kenny'

211, 23, 'Conny'
```

When I reach the third line, how can I throw an error and continue reading the remaining lines?

Comment: The short answer is, don't try to use `fscanf`.  Read entire lines of text at a time, perhaps using `fgets`.  For each line that you read, process it, either by calling `sscanf`, or breaking it up into tokens using `strtok`, or by some other technique.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scanf error handling C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969084/scanf-error-handling-c)

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969084/scanf-error-handling-c